# Every minute error in log - Error: 17053, Severity: 16, State: 1

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ms-office

I turned on this commands:

```
EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
```

And from that point every minute I get the following error log:

```
Error: 17053, Severity: 16, State: 1.
UpdateUptimeRegKey: Operating system error 5(Access is denied.) encountered.
```

I read [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/error-17053-updateuptimeregkey-operating-system-error-5-access/ba-p/2375619) but I dont fully understand what I need to do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, regardless of a package's virtual registry setup, the virtual registry must be explicitly bypassed for specific keys, notably for registry writes. This implies that data sent to these keys will be written to the native registry directly (or attempt to do so).

So, with Office Click-to-Run, the only option to avoid registry virtualization is to put the required registry entries as mentioned here:

> For the same we have added (Don't overwrite it) the required SQL reg
> key(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer) to the list of exceptions at
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\AppV\Subsystem\VirtualRegistry
> under “passthroughPaths” and this fixed the issue.

Please refer the links here, for more insights: [Registry Pass-Through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/gladiatormsft/app-v-on-virtual-registry-nomenclature) and  Office Click-To-Run and PassThroughPaths - [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b352d803-a358-42e3-94b7-d40285bb43e2/office-clicktorun-and-passthroughpaths)